# What is an alternate solution to nested multiple FOR loops?

Tags: design-patterns, for-loop, language-agnostic, logic

It is always recommended to avoid multiple and nested `for` loops in your programming. But there are some cases where we have to use it. Is there any solution ("good practice" or design pattern) with which we can achieve the same result by reducing the computation time.

I would like to know a generic optimized logic which will replace multiple and nested for loop.

**Note:** This is not specific to any programming language.

Comment: I think it depends on the situation , sometime `switch-case` can be handy as well .

Comment: Is there a relation between the different loops? Because if yes, there might be a smart way those loops can be combined; if they are not related, probably each loops serves its own purpose and my answer below might help, although it's mainly cosmetic.

Comment: There is no generic algorithm to substitute a loop. Without more specific business logic example is very hard to propose ideas... if any.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do is using one loop per function, i.e. split multiple for loops into multiple functions, each performing one loop, e.g. (pseudo language):

```
execute_boxes(Boxes boxes)
   for each box in boxes:
      execute_box(box)

execute_box(Box box)
    for each side in box:
        ...
```

Comment: But, the numbers of computation cycles remain same. This is just a cosmetic solution and not optimized.

Comment: I know, but otherwise some more context is needed. I will add a comment to your question that might help others to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without any specific example of situation I think, but some languages offer you for example parallel loops, so many threads can make some work in loop. Also simple refactoring is a good option - I mean seperate your loops in different methods.